# Deploying Sails to a standard web server (Windows)?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Today I discovered Sails and have been watching a few tutorials. One thing I can't seem to work and find out is how to deploy it to a standard web server, like for example via an FTP client. I've seen the tutorial on how to deploy it to a Heroku account, but this isn't really what I'm after, as we already rent a Windows 2012 server.

I've got a feeling I'm completely missing something here, so can someone please help me out :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer all files via FTP to your Webserver (include all node-modules).

But you have to make sure NodeJS is installed on your server. Than login into your Server (e.g. via SSH) and start your Sails-App (`node app.js`)

Comment: Ok but then all the node-modules are 100 MB +?. 
Does Node/sails work independently of IIS then?

Comment: Yes you have to transfer them or run `npm install` on your server. Yes NodeJS run independently from IIS. Google `IIS nodejs` - maybe you have to change a view things because you surely want to use Port 80 from outside - ISS use Port 80 on default